# Jest cannot resolve imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

Jest somehow cannot resolve the secondary imports of my files.

**MyTest.js** has this line :

```
import reducer from "./../AppReducer"
```

**AppReducer.js** has this line  :

```
import { ActionXYZ} from './Actions.js'
```

For ActionXYZ cannot be resolved. If I debug the code then the ActionXYZ is an object with two strings and looks like this :

```
message: "ReferenceError: ActionsXYZ is not defined"
stack "ReferenceError: ActionXYZ is not defined
    at eval (eval at t.evaluate (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source)), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at t.evaluate (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:165:98)
    at DebugCommandProcessor.t.processDebugJSONRequest (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:458:15)
    at AppReducer (C:\dev\react-charts\src\js\AppReducer.js:11:37)
    at dispatch (C:\dev\react-charts\node_modules\redux\lib\createStore.js:178:22)
```

Why is Jest doing this? My application otherwise runs normally.

My jest config setup in my **package.json** looks like this :

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "./test/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/test/styleMock.js"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Post your jest config setup

Comment: done..............

Comment: How do you export `ActionXYZ` in `Actions.js`?

Comment: it seems to have fixed itself up. I just moved some code around a bit. I think the imports where getting a bit messed up. As a test it wasn't running some code that was running if running as a client by itself.